# Tmux border split in rxvt

Tags: ssh, windows, tmux, unicode, rxvt

I'm attempting to connect to my Arch server running tmux from my work Windows PC. I've found that while Console2 does a decent job with most things, it's not perfect, and I get all sorts of graphical glitches (fault of my semi-complex configurations).

I'd like to use rxvt to keep things simple (I'd rather not have the overhead of an X server for rxvt-unicode). However, when I split windows in tmux, the borders appear as a set of garbage bytes that are represented as `€â”`.

Is it possible to have a regular border when using tmux and rxvt (non-unicode)?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an character encoding issue. What is your system character encoding?

Comment: Since I'm using the Consolas font, I believe Windows has UTF8 available. My server is set to UTF8 as well, and I haven't defined any encoding changes to tmux...

Comment: It may be available, but whether it is actually enabled is another matter.

Comment: Ah I see... so regular old rxvt should be capable of displaying those UTF8 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain `€â”`, I would have expected `â”‚` which is the Windows-1252 interpretation of the bytes that encode `│` in UTF-8. `│` is what Tmux uses for vertical borders between windows. But you evidently have an encoding mismatch.

Run `locale` to see what your locale settings are. The Windows native port of Rxvt in Cygwin doesn't support UTF-8, so you need to set an 8-bit locale. Specifically, the `LC_CTYPE` category must not end in `utf8` (or `utf-8` or `UTF8` or `UTF-8`).

The real solution is to use [MinTTY](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) (it's shipped with Cygwin) or [PuTTYcyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/). Both are derived from [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and support UTF-8. See also [How do you configure a Windows machine for a Linux user?](https://superuser.com/questions/282397/how-do-you-configure-a-windows-machine-for-a-linux-user/282762#282762)

Comment: Thanks for the full answer! I'll have to investigate the particular encoding problems at a later date, as getting MinTTY set up was quite simple. (I would have tried it first, but I've got a terrible allergy to windows-only software!)